# Angular.js, router-ui and Bootstrap: Activate State of Clicked Button

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have this nav.html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
  <li ng-class="{ active: $state.includes('home') }"><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
  <li ng-class="{ active: $state.includes('about') }"><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
  <li ng-class="{ active: $state.includes('contact') }"><a ui-sref="contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<h3 class="text-muted">my page title</h3>
</div
```

This Controller:

```
.module('app', [
    'ui.router'
])
.config(['$urlRouterProvider','$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider,$stateProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
.state('about', {
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: 'templates/about.html',
        controller: 'aboutCtrl'
     })
  // and so forth
```

Now when I click a button in the navigation, the ui-router correctly displays tha page and changes the url in the browser adress bar. However Bootstrap does not make the button activated, aka selected or color it grey etc. How to achieve this the angular way?

Comment: Have you made sure the `$state` service is available on the scope where your navbar is?

Comment: Nope I did not define any navbar properties in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must make sure that `$state` service is defined/injected in your current scope. You may have a `navCtrl` that handles the rendering logic of your navbar html. Remember to inject that controller in your `nav.html`:

```
<ul ng-controller = "navCtrl" class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
```

Next, write a `boolean` function inside your `navCtrl` to check the current state, using `$state.includes`:

```
.controller('navCtrl',['$scope','$state','$location',function($scope,$state,$location){  
   $scope.isState = function(states){
     return $state.includes(states);
   };
}])
```

and lastly use this function in your html:

```
<li ng-class="{active: isState('home') }">
 <a ui-sref="home">Home</a>
</li>
```

Here is the [working plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ohgbL3SrcOUSyqx5NRsI?p=info).

Comment: Great answer, working too. I have a doubt: Why do you define "//the rest of the controllers." below the "parent" .controller, don't I have the routers defined in "ui.router.state.."?

Comment: Yes you can. It's either you define your string literal of your controllers, or you can directly write the controller as functions at your `stateProvider`. Just the matter of design. I separate declaration and usage because it is cleaner that way, and rather modular too :)